# How to test if my app can connect with https and fallback to http otherwise?

Tags: java, android, http, https, httpurlconnection

I use the Java `HttpURLConnection` to connect with my server:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
try {
  connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
} catch (IOException e) {
  logger.severe("ConnectionImpl - request(): IOException e: "+e.getMessage());
  e.printStackTrace();
}
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
try {
    connection.connect(); 
  } catch (IOException e) {
    logger.severe("ConnectionImpl - request(): IOException e: "+e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
int statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

**How can I test if my app can connect with https and fail back to http if this fails?**

Comment: Falling back to HTTP defeats almost the entire purpose of HTTPS (except for strictly passive attackers).  **Don't do that**!

Comment: This is only in case when http in not available for some reason.

Comment: The only likely reason that HTTPS would be unavailable is that an attacker is blocking HTTPS connections so that they can read or modify the HTTP response.  **Don't do this**!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that by applying check on status code as following:

```
int statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();
if(statusCode==200){
Log.d("Connection Status","Can connect");
}
else{
Log.d("Connection Status","Can't connect");
}
```

or

```
if(statusCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
    Log.d("Connection Status","Can connect");
    }
    else{
    Log.d("Connection Status","Can't connect");
    }
```

Comment: And how do I change the protocol to http or do I have to change the complete url?

Comment: yes you will have to change the url or part of url string which consists of http/https